# JSON object not formatting properly

Tags: json

I have some code that fetches data from an API and writes it to a file, the API returns tokenIdMetadata that has a bunch of information in it that I do not want so I made it into a new JSON object tokenMetadata and save that to a file as seen below.

```
const tokenIdMetadata = await Moralis.Web3API.token.getTokenIdMetadata(options);
const tokenMetadata = {};
tokenMetadata.token_id = tokenIdMetadata.token_id;
tokenMetadata.metadata = tokenIdMetadata.metadata;
fs.writeFileSync(folderName.concat('/', collectionSlug, '_', tokenID, '.json'), JSON.stringify(tokenMetadata, null, 4));
```

The problem is the code returns a string in the JSON file that is not formatted properly

```
 "token_id": "4",
 "metadata": "{\"name\":\"Arcade Land Mega #4\",\"image\":\"ipfs://QmaJyxmwWkH17P7cpzRDFqcQwh7HYZ53VS9pJN3rtWKVPh\",\"description\":\"Arcade Lands are digital properties in an interoperable metaverse that serves as your web3 home for all your NFTs. Land owners will get additional benefits within the Arcadeverse.\",\"attributes\":[{\"trait_type\":\"Size\",\"value\":\"Mega\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Area\",\"value\":\"Frozen\"},{\"trait_type\":\"Underground\",\"value\":\"Weird Rocks\"}]}"
```

This is how it should be formatted

```
"token_id" : "4",
"metadata" : {
  name: 'Arcade Land Mega #4',
  image: 'ipfs://QmXYYbVEFqVPRELzPN3fgCw9v3wr2iQqixbVaGS1JTH6mS',
  description: 'Arcade Lands are digital properties in an interoperable metaverse that serves as your web3 home for all your NFTs. Land owners will get additional benefits within the Arcadeverse.',
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Size', value: 'Mega' },
    { trait_type: 'Area', value: 'Frozen' },
    { trait_type: 'Underground', value: 'Weird Rocks' }
  ]
}
```

I was wondering how I would go about fixing this.

Comment: The value you put in `tokenMetadata.metadata` is a string (a JSON), not an object. The final JSON is formatted correctly. To get what you want, parse `tokenIdMetadata.metadata` as JSON and store the decoded object in `tokenMetadata.metadata`. Read more about [JSON](https://json.org)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked example result of this API call in the documentation https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/web3-api/token#gettokenidmetadata . It  looks like this is about failing to decode incoming JSON.
I think replacing `tokenIdMetadata.metadata` by `JSON.parse(tokenIdMetadata.metadata)` should fix that.

The final code should look like the following:

```js
const tokenIdMetadata = await Moralis.Web3API.token.getTokenIdMetadata(options);
const tokenMetadata = {};
tokenMetadata.token_id = tokenIdMetadata.token_id;
tokenMetadata.metadata = JSON.parse(tokenIdMetadata.metadata);
fs.writeFileSync(folderName.concat('/', collectionSlug, '_', tokenID, '.json'), JSON.stringify(tokenMetadata, null, 4));
```

Comment: Cheers for the suggestion I tried that but doing that results in the following error ```SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1```

Comment: @Ben this error occurs when JSON.parse is given invalid JSON as input. are you sure you replaced the proper thing correctly? I'll update the answer with the resulting code, please verify your code using that.